# A SQL query showing unwanted resluts (when joining 3 tables)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been searching for a solution for this problem for quite sometime, i found some similar problems to mine but non of the proposed solution worked.

I want to join these 3 tables.

(1) **ADM**

- `AID` = Primary Key
- `BedNo` = int

(2) **ADMdeposite**:

- `DID` = Primary Key
- `AID` = Foreign key
- `Dvalue` = money
- `Dvalue` = Date

(3)  **Reservation**:

- `ID` = Primary Key
- `AID` = Foreign key
- `Type` = Nvchar
- `Value` = Money
- `Pname` = Nvarchar

I used this query

```
SELECT        
    Reservation.AID, Reservation.type, Reservation.value, Reservation.pname, 
    ADMdeposit.Ddate, ADMdeposit.Dvalue
FROM
    ADM 
INNER JOIN
    ADMdeposit ON ADM.AID = ADMdeposit.AID 
INNER JOIN
    Reservation ON ADM.AID = Reservation.AID
```

I get the wanted results however the problem is, the `ADMdeposite.Dvalue` cell duplicates itself to the total number of `Reservation.Type` number of cells

Here is a print screen of the actual data in the `ADMdeposite.Dvalue` table

[image]

Here is the result of the query:

[image]

Here is the result I WANT:

[image]

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: "the problem is, the ADMdeposite.Dvalue cell duplicates itself" that is what it is supposed to do when doing a 1 to Many/Many to Many query and it is on the side of the join whose data is replicated.  if you want it to do something else what is your desired outcome?  allocated/Split equally by the number of reservations records that match each ADM and or ADM deposit? only be populated on first or certain type? Or perhaps only select 1 reservation per ADM & ADM deposit so that it is 1 to 1 instead?  if the latter how to identify which Reservation records to choose?

Comment: You have 2 reservation types for AID=1, so the ADM row is pulled in twice and also ADMDeposit. Can you show the resultset you wanted? It's better to copy & paste the output as text in your question - that way people can copy it to work with it themselves.

Comment: Let's say there are three deposits for an ADM and four reservations. Joining these records gives you 3x4=12 rows. So you combine every deposit with every reservation, although they are not really related. What gives you the idea to join them? Why not two queries, one to show the deposits, one for the reservations?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL server 2008.

Comment: here is an explanation of what I want the query to do exactly.
- ADM can have many ADMdeposites and Many ReservationsTYPES , yet the number of Deposites doesnt have to equal the number of Reservations.


meaning , lets assume for ADM no1 ,  has only 1 Deposite (Did1= 1000$ 
and 3 different TYPES and values of Reservation ( Rid1= 300$ ,Rid2=200$, and Rid3= 50$ ) which means AMD1 has a remaining balance of 450$)

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments and seeing that your goal is to calculate balances (deposits minus reservations), I would suggest summing the amounts of all deposits for each adm, do the same for the reservations, then join those 2 results together in order to calculate the balance :

```
SELECT d.aid, 
       d.TotalDeposits, 
       r.TotalReservations, 
       d.TotalDeposits - r.TotalReservations as Balance 
FROM
(SELECT ADMdeposit.aid, SUM(ADMdeposit.dvalue) as TotalDeposits
FROM ADMdeposit GROUP BY ADMdeposit.aid) as d

INNER JOIN

(SELECT Reservation.AID, SUM(Reservation.value) as TotalReservations
FROM Reservation GROUP BY Reservation.AID) as r
ON d.AID = r.AID
```

Comment: Sir , this is exactly what i NEEDED except for the part which the Pname from reservation is missing and i would like to have the Pname showing next to the AID.

thank you so much

EDITED:

i have already added Pname to the query now everything is perfect

thanks again FSmardGIS

Comment: I used this query to get the exact result.

SELECT 

       d.aid,
       d.TotalDeposits, 
       r.TotalReservations,
       r.pname,
        d.TotalDeposits - r.TotalReservations as Balance 
FROM
(SELECT  ADMdeposit.aid, SUM(ADMdeposit.dvalue) as TotalDeposits
FROM ADMdeposit GROUP BY ADMdeposit.aid) as d

INNER JOIN

(SELECT Reservation.pname,Reservation.AID, SUM(Reservation.value) as TotalReservations
FROM Reservation GROUP BY Reservation.pname,Reservation.AID) as r
ON d.AID = r.AID